# Disable Notepad++ Font Zoom using Ctrl+Mousewheel

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, fonts

I am going to ask something that goes opposite to common understanding which is "*more power to the user, the better it is*".

I like the flexibility of increasing/decreasing the font size with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mousewheel</kbd>. But as I use it more, I feel it becomes a nuisance (due to my own undoing).

Is there a way to disable this shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mousewheel</kbd>)?

Comment: Ctrl+mousewheel does not change font size in my Notepad++ ... but see this link [Disable Control Scroll Zoom-in and Zoom-out in Notepad++ - Code2Care](http://code2care.org/pages/disable-control-scroll-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-in-notepadplusplus/)

Comment: Well, zoom-disabler plugin is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Adding as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is there a way to disable this shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mousewheel</kbd> )?

You can install the [zoom-disabler](http://code2care.org/pages/disable-control-scroll-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-in-notepadplusplus/) plugin:

> You can Zoom-in or Zoom-out in Notepad++ using,
>
> 1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mousewheel</kbd>  Scroll-in or Scroll-out.
> 2. Keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>NumpadPlus</kbd> to Zoom-in or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad Minus</kbd> to Zoom-out.
>
> But many a times we Zoom happens by accident.
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse</kbd>  get pressed so Zoom takes place
>   instead of Scroll. In order to disable this functionality you need to
>   download a plugin called "Zoom Disabler"
>
> **Installing Zoom Disabler**
>
> 1. Goto Menu -> Plugins -> Plugin Manager
>
>    [image: Zoom Disable Plugin]
> 2. Look for Zoom Disabler and Select the Check-box and Install
> 3. After Installing the Plugin Notepad++ will restart and "Zoom Disabler" will be available under Plugins Menu.
> 4. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseWheel</kbd>  in or out. Text will remain unaffected.
>
> When you install this plugin, by default it Disables Mouse Zoom. If
>   you want to enable it again you can do it by going to Menu -> Plugins
>   -> Plugin Manager -> Zoom Disabler and de-select Disables Mouse Zoom
>
> [image: Zoom Disabler Settings]

Source [Disable Control Scroll Zoom-in and Zoom-out in Notepad++ - Code2Care](http://code2care.org/pages/disable-control-scroll-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-in-notepadplusplus/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/) (if you haven't yet). 
Then use this script:

```
SendMode Input 

#If winActive("ahk_exe notepad++.exe")

^wheelup::
return

^wheeldown::
return
```

This will disable Ctrl+wheel for N++. If you want to disable the zoom on Ctrl+wheel feature in other programs too, you can simply add those to the `#If` line, e.g. to disable it in Firefox also change this line to:

```
#If winActive("ahk_exe notepad++.exe")
 or winActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
```